# Best way to custom style the packages installed in Angular application

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have came across this couple of times and have been in back of my mind for sometime. When we install any packages in our angular applications and use the same in any of the component, it often need custom styling to match the design. So when we apply style in the component css file where we have used the package, it doesn't reflects. When i apply the same style in the root style.css it gets reflected.

I would like to keep my main style.css file clean. What is the best way to custom style the plugins which we have installed in the application. i am not sure whether it is the correct way to put all such styles in the main style.css file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a 'best' way to do this. However, I'd recommend adding an extra CSS file and adding the path of the new CSS files to the `angular.json`'s `styles` array. This way you can create a file for each dependency.

If your CSS doesn't overwrite the CSS from the dependencies, try adding `::ng-deep` selector before your CSS. What works most with Angular Material is overwriting styling in the class selectors.